# Is "call something/somebody to somebody" a normal collocation?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> “You must have shown me real loyalty down in the Chamber. **Nothing but that could have called Fawkes to you**.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

I haven't found the use of "*call something/somebody to somebody*" in dictionaries. I think it means "... *called Fawkes to help you*." Is it a normal collocation? What's the exact meaning it conveys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Call** *someone or something* **to** *a person or place* is a phrase synonymous with the verb **summon**.

> The boss called me to his office yesterday.
>
> Call the puppy to you and see if it comes over.
>
> An ambulance was called to the scene.
>
> The Attorney General was called to the White House.

P.S. That which 'calls to' the summoned need not have an actual voice.

> Rumors of gold nuggets as big as a bird's egg called them to the Yukon by the thousands.
>
> The promise of opportunity called them to the big city.

And there the verb takes on a figurative sense, 'to draw or attract *as if* by calling'.

Comment: In this context, the subject(Nothing but that, referring to "shown me real loyalty down in the Chamber") is not a person. How should we understand it?

Comment: Please see the P.S.

Comment: Is this definition "*To cause one to think of (something); evoke.*" fit for this sense?

Comment: No, that would be "to call *to mind*".  *These skyscrapers looming over the street call to mind a great canyon.*  In other words, "summon thoughts of ..."  But "to mind" is required.

Answer (score 2):

I've searched what is the nature of Fawkes. For those like me that don't remember it, he's a magical phoenix.

I don't remember that exact scene either but I think that it may be related with these construction quoted from the Cambridge Dictionary

[**bring/call sth/sb to heel**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/bring-call-sth-sb-to-heel)

> to order a dog to come close to you
>   to force someone to obey you

Fawkes is a magical animal so probably he obeyed or came close to Harry because the young wizard showed real loyalty previously.

Comment: Unfortunately this interpretation doesn’t quite fit because Harry Potter does not actually call Fawkes. The situation he’s in is desperate and Fawkes, magically perceiving this despite being a distance away, comes of his own volition and initiative. He is being called to Harry by the situation, not by Harry. (It’s a common theme of the books that the protagonist doesn’t actually have any agency and gets handed the solution without working for it.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point. You're right. My Harry Potter's books are in Spanish and I've not looked up the reference. Thanks for the clarification. :-)